# foreach missing controls unless nested and repeated

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, foreach, nested-loops

I have a `foreach` loop inside of an button-click event handler that I'm using to get rid of controls that all sit on the same point on the Y axis.  I have a control that adds a row, and then I need users to have the option to remove a row they didn't mean to add.

When I use the `foreach` loop by itself, it consistently misses two items--the same two every time. I've confirmed that the Y values are in fact identical. If I keep running the function, it removes all the controls on the row after three runs.  However, if I nest the `foreach` loop, using all the same values, it works.  See the code below.

This seems like a pretty sloppy way to do it, but it's also the only solution that has worked for me. I saw a couple other posts that said to declare a second variable within the loop (i.e., `Control z = c;  if(z.Location....)`).  That didn't make any difference in the behavior here.  Can anyone explain why the `foreach` loop by itself isn't working?  How do I fix it without the repetitive nesting?

Working:

```
    internal void MinButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("Record" + arrDynamY[0].ToString());
        foreach (Control c in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
            {
                c.Dispose();
            }

            foreach (Control ctrl in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
                {
                    ctrl.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Misses the same two controls every time:

```
    internal void MinButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("Record" + arrDynamY[0].ToString());
        foreach (Control c in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
            {
                c.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not overly familiar with how WinForms work, but by disposing the control while you're iterating, you're probably invalidating the collection state which could be causing a problem.

Comment: At first blush, could it be related to removing items from a collection that you are iterating over? That is because when you call Dispose() on the control, it stays till GC kicks in.

Comment: You shouldn't dispose control, that is in iterated loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should firstly obtain controls for removing and remove them afterwards like this:

```
var controlsToRemove = from Control c in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls
                       where c.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1]
                       select c;

foreach (var c in controlsToRemove.ToArray())
{
    Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls.Remove(c);
    c.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I like your solution more then mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying (disposing in this case) the items of a collection you're iterating on, I believe that's what causes unexpected behavior, you can do it with a `for` loop to avoid this problem:

```
        for (int i = Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls.Length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            if (Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls[i].Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
                Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls[i].Dispose();
```

I presumed that `Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls` can be accessed as array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do the dispose in a seperate loop, it might have affect on other controls

Try this

```
internal void MinButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("Record" + arrDynamY[0].ToString());
    var controlsToDispose = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control c in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
        {
            controlsToDispose.Add(c);
        }
    }
    foreach (Control c in controlsToDispose )
    {
        c.Dispose();
    }              
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because when you call Dispose() on the control, it stays in memory only till GC kicks in. Try following.

```
List<Control> controlsToDispose = new List<Control>();
foreach (Control c in Scratch.tScratch.panel2.Controls)
{
       if (c.Location.Y == arrDynamY[1])
       {
           controlsToDispose.Add(c);
           c.Dispose();
       }
}
while(controlsToDispose.Count>0)
{
      Control ctrl = controlsToDispose[0];
      controlsToDispose.RemoveAt(0);
      ctrl.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `"It's because when you call Dispose() on the control, it stays in memory only till GC kicks in."` That's just not true.  Disposing of an object doesn't have anything to do with the GC.

Comment: @Servy upon some research I realised you are right. I was under the impression that Dispose flags the object as ready to be GC'ed. So thanks for the correction. However the main point of the answer above holds, i.e. it is possible that the object was GC'ed while the collection is being iterated over. Therefore -1 is still too harsh :)